# Jquery not recognize menu include

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my index calls from other HTML pages using the library [CSI.js](https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js)

my index:

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-2" id="nav">
  <div data-include="./views/menu/sticky-menu.html"></div> <!-- menu -->
</div>
```

in menu page:

```
<div class="sticky-menu" id="sticky-menu">
  <div class="sticky-menu-header">
    <img class="logo" src="./img/logo-branco.svg" />
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-glass"></i>Eventos </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>Alertas </a><span class="sticky-menu-label">4 </span></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Indicadores </a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Teste</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teste </a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Teste </a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Teste </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Consulting </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>Grafana </a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 0 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1 </a><span class="sticky-menu-label">10 </span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

submenu have dropdown animation with jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#sticky-menu").jqueryAccordionMenu();
});
```

On the menu page (sticky-menu.html) it works fine, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAPds.png

Notice that the `+` sign appears when clicked:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OJIu.png

However, not index.html, menu (jquery) does not work:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvBRR.png

When I enter the code in the console:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#sticky-menu").jqueryAccordionMenu();
});
```

it works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZe8y.png

I've included the js code on both pages, I think it's silly, but I really can not. Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**
I noticed that my sticky-menu.html is wearing after the script. How to solve?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Pzu.png

**EDIT 2 :**

I solved with requireJS.

Comment: When you call that code in your index page, the #sticky-menu element isn't a part of the index DOM yet. The reason it works when you do from console is because it has finished loading and exists in the page.

Comment: And where is this `jqueryAccordionMenu()` function because it isn't mentioned in csi.js?

Comment: @basic how i fix that?

Comment: @DREAMTEK in main.js and it works

Comment: Jota what code you enter in console?

Comment: @Jota use a mutationobserver to check the dom for the element.

Comment: @MishelParkour  
  jQuery("#sticky-menu").jqueryAccordionMenu();

Answer (score -1):

You could run some code as follows

```
function waitForElement(id, callback){
    var checkForElement = setInterval(function(){
        if(document.getElementById(id)){
            clearInterval(checkForElement);
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}

waitForElement("idOfElementToWaitFor", function(){
    alert("element is loaded.. do stuff");
});
```

Where your `id` for your element would be `#sticky-menu` and your callback function would be `jQuery("#sticky-menu").jqueryAccordionMenu();`